# jQuery code to display images served by PHP, without reloading

Tags: jquery

My php page displays a slider of images and when the user clicks on an image(.item), the div below (#team_single) changes the content without reloading the page. Content of the div changes also when the user clicks the arrow of the slider (.slick-prev, .slick-next, .slick-arrow).

I'm looking for a way to optimize my following code.

I have made a function team_push for the code repetition but still I know it can be better than that !

```
function team_push($image, $position, $sousposition, $title, $content) {
    $('#team_single .single-img').html($image);
    $('#team_single .position').html($position);
    $('#team_single .sousposition').html($sousposition);
    $('#team_single .title').html($title);
    $('#team_single .description').html($content);
}
var image = $('.slick-current').find("img").clone();
var position = $('.slick-current .position').html();
var sousposition = $('.slick-current .sousposition').html();
var title = $('.slick-current .title').html();
var content = $('.slick-current .content').html();
team_push(image, position, sousposition, title, content);

$('#team_slider .item').on('click', function(){
    var image = $(this).find("img").clone();
    var position = $(this).find('.position').html();
    var sousposition = $(this).find('.sousposition').html();
    var title = $(this).find('.title').html();
    var content = $(this).find('.content').html();
    team_push(image, position, sousposition, title, content);
});
$('#team_slider .slick-arrow').on('click', function(){
    var image = $('.slick-current').find("img").clone();
    var position = $('.slick-current .position').html();
    var sousposition = $('.slick-current .sousposition').html();
    var title = $('.slick-current .title').html();
    var content = $('.slick-current .content').html();
    team_push(image, position, sousposition, title, content);
});
$('#team_single .slick-prev').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#team_slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToScroll', 1, true);
    $('#team_slider').slick('slickPrev');
    var image = $('.slick-current').find("img").clone();
    var position = $('.slick-current .position').html();
    var sousposition = $('.slick-current .sousposition').html();
    var title = $('.slick-current .title').html();
    var content = $('.slick-current .content').html();
    team_push(image, position, sousposition, title, content);
});
$('#team_single .slick-next').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#team_slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToScroll', 1, true);
    $('#team_slider').slick('slickNext');
    var image = $('.slick-current').find("img").clone();
    var position = $('.slick-current .position').html();
    var sousposition = $('.slick-current .sousposition').html();
    var title = $('.slick-current .title').html();
    var content = $('.slick-current .content').html();
    team_push(image, position, sousposition, title, content);
});
```

I need less lines of codes :)

Comment: Some HTML would help this question immeasurably.

Comment: We generally fix bugs here rather than do refactoring or "optimisation" (which could potentially refer to a lot of different issues). You could see if your question would be better received at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/